# Set build.gradle value to a value written in xml file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-resources

Is there away to set a variable in the `build.gradle` file to a value set in the `strings.xml` file?

For example say I have this in my `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="version">"1.0.0"</string>
```

And in my `build.gradle` file I had something along these lines:

```
 versionName: @strings/version
```

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, as of now it's unavailable to read from string resource files, Android Gradle Plugin does **not** have such an API.

Instead, you can do the opposite using [`resValue()`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:resValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) API: you can write a value to resources within `build.gradle`:

```
resValue "string", "variable_name", "some value here"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle.properties, write the key/value. eg

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.0
```

And in build.gradle set the config via buildConfigField method.
i.e `buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "" +VERSION_NAME+ "")`
Compile the code and you can get it like this `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`